# How to do Column Mapping for a CSV file while uploading using c#

Tags: c#, csv, columnmappings

Can we do column mapping while uploading a CSV File.

I have a system, which will upload CSV files and store the data into SQL Server tables. But some records of the tables are wrong.

The records are wrong because, the data is split into 2 or more lines, but all the lines will have the same amount of commas, just as same as the number of commas we have for heading. So this cause wrong data to enter in columns.

So if I can map the columns while uploading the CSV and if it can show me the lines which have errors, it could possibly solve this issue.

Can anyone help plz?

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: Read a line, split it on commas - if the number of strings is not correct, append the next line & repeat.

Comment: I am unable to add sample data. Since I am new here, I don't have privilege to do so

Comment: @PaulF I am doing this the same way you have mentioned. But my issue is, for some records, say a record has 12 columns, then the 12 columns are split into 3 rows and each row will contain 11 commas. Since I am using commas as delimitter, I will get wrong data for fields

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - if each of the three rows has 11 commas then isn't each row valid. Can you show example good lines & bad lines

Comment: Good lines are -: 5/1/2015,10101,Atul,ADMIN,8 HOURS SHIFT,0:00,0:00,Absence,,,0:00,0:00,0:00
5/2/2015,10101,Atul,ADMIN,8 HOURS SHIFT,0:00,0:00,Absence,,,0:00,0:00,0:00

Comment: Bad lines are -: 5/3/2015,10101,Atul,ADMIN,8 HOURS SHIFT,7:40,16:20,Late In,In,,,,
,Out,,,,,,,,,,,
,7:40,0:00,7:40,,,,,,,,,
5/4/2015,10101,Atul,ADMIN,8 HOURS SHIFT,7:47,16:02,Late In,In,,,,
,Out,,,,,,,,,,,
,7:40,0:00,7:40,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

For CSV parsing I tend to use the Jet engine, it is great for parsing CSV files.

There is a great example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom

Thanks
Jamie